# How to write one js var value inside input html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The var `inc` is incrementing using ajax below:

```
var inc = 100;
jQuery('.mybuttonin').click(function()
{
      jQuery.ajax
      ({
          url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            'action':'myaction',
            value : inc
          },
          success: function(data)
          {
                inc = data;
                alert(inc);
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
                console.log(data);
          }
      });

});
```

I want this var to put inside an input id and name:

```
<input id='wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]' name='wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]' value='100%'>
```

how can i do this? the above input is dynamically creating.

Comment: id in this format `id='wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]'` not a good practices, and jQuery `ajax` default have asynchronous manner, so you will need to manipulate `element` in `success` callback function

Comment: can you tell me how can i do this in success function?

Comment: as you mentioned in question, the element is dynamically creating, so element creation should execute before `ajax` and put values using right selector like `$("input[name^=wpjobus_resume_skills]")` start with `wpjobus_resume_skills` name or use another right selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your element is already created use this.

```
$('.input_element_class').attr(
            { id: 'wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]', name: 'wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]', type: 'text', value:'100%'}
);
```

if you want to create an element you can do something similar.

```
$('<input />').attr(
            { id: 'wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]', name: 'wpjobus_resume_skills['+inc+'][1]', type: 'text', value:'100%'}
).appendTo('.parent_elemnt_class');
```

Comment: i tried to append the input but it didn't append. my alert() also didn't worked when using your second code.

Comment: sorry I put value="100%" where as it should be  value : "100%", ive fixed it now please try.